# skrollr conflicts bx slider custom pager?

Tags: jquery, html, bxslider, pager, skrollr

This is my first time asking a question here, I'm quite a noob so don't be mad at me if I mess up a little.

The thing is, I am doin a one page web based on skrollr:  https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

and I use this fantastic slider called BX Slider: http://bxslider.com/

I have already put two of the three sliders i need (those works great). The problem comes when I try to make a custom pager in the third slider using this HTML code BX slider provides me:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/730_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg" /></li>
</ul>

<div id="bx-pager">
  <a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img src="/images/thumbs/tree_root.jpg" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="/images/thumbs/houses.jpg" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img src="/images/thumbs/hill_fence.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

The problem is, when I click one of those pager items it redirects me to index.html not allowing me to interact with the actual slider.

As you may know, Skrollr library use the HTML5 `data-` attributes to define multiple sets of styles (they call each of them keyframe) and skrollr interpolates between them. In a skrollr basic example...

```
<div data-0="background-color:rgb(0,0,255);" data-500="background-color:rgb(255,0,0);">
WOOOT
</div>
```

So my guess is... could it be they are in conflict with that data- attribute in both codes?? if so, Why doesn't that bother me when the code is in default bx-slider pager??

How could I fix this? Any Ideas?

Thanks for the help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML only needs:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="/images/pic1.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic2.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic3.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

You should initialize the structure, call .bxslider() on

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

Then, you can try to change the css styles in order to improve the appearance with:

```
.bx-pager-link{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url('/images/pic1.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-size: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer dgomez,

I already have it working like that in my site, the problem comes when i want to use custom pager with thumbnails, then I need to use the second part of the code, 
but for some reason it doesnt work. and I think the problem is a conflict with another jquery i'm using on the site.